# Dynamic controls ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In web page, created controls dynamically and when select dropdown item ddl do not remember selected item

**example**

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // create

    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_selectedIndexChanged);
    ddl.AutoPostBack = true;

    //....

    Page.Controls.Add(ddl);

    // Fill dropdownlist when page loaded first time

    ddl.DataSource = LoadFormDataBase;
    ddl.DataBind();
}

protected void ddl_selectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //
}
```

When selected dropdown item web page recreated and my selected item disappear, ViewState do not work. This dynamic controls often used and I have an doubt to use Session?

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i

Comment: problem not in creating, problem in save selected item

Comment: That's related to retaining the state of the control, which is what I gave you link for.

Comment: Additionally, be careful with loading the DropDowns with new data which happens in PageLoad, you should make a check whether the page is postback or not.

Comment: i am checking when page postbak, this is not all code

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below way:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/502251/How-to-create-controls-dynamically-in-ASP-NET-and

You need to handle viewstate carefully.